# なっ at the start of a sentence

Tags: words, contractions

The parents are comparing themselves to comedy characters:

> Father:「**なっ**長さん」
>   Narrator: 長さんと言われたお母さんはにがりきった顔になった。
>   Father: ??
>   Narrator: Mum, who had been called Chou, made a bitter face.

I can only imagine that なっ is a contraction of あなたは but that seems to be a bit of a stretch. What is the correct interpretation, and when is it appropriate to use it?

Comment: Do you have a few lines before the line in question? And to be sure, 長さん is definitely 長{ちょう}さん and not 長{なが}さん?

Comment: Yeah, if that's なが, that's just straight-up hesitation/stuttering.

Comment: ^「[長]{ちょう}さん」っていうと、普通は[この人](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%82%84%E9%95%B7%E4%BB%8B)・・・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「なっ」＝「な」＝「なあ」

Among those, 「なあ」 would be the "dictionary" form.

This is an ***interjection*** that is often used to address a person or call someone's attention.

***One thing Japanese-learners should remember is that we only use this interjection with people who we know well and who are equals or below us in age and/or social status***.

You do not use it with your boss, a stranger, etc. under normal circumstances.  You would sound very rude if you did.

Answer (score 2):

な is basically the same as ね in this context, and it basically just means "hey," or something you use to get someone's attention. A っ at the end of a word just means the last sound is dragged out a bit.